# How to disable Next Up Card on playlist's last video in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer on a video playlist, i have activated the  next up card, as is shown on the next image. (reference image)

[image: next up card]

The problem is when the last chapter of a playlist is player and the Next Up card is displayed it shows the first video on the playlist.

I'm trying to disable the next up card only on the last video of a playlist.

This is with jwplayer 7 with API. i tried to change the setup of the jwplayer but that refresh the entire player.

```
componentWillMount() {

  const player = this.getPlayer() //this only get my player
  player.on('play', this.playHandler)
}

playHandler() {
  const player = this.getPlayer()

  if(this.props.currentChapter === this.props.playlist.length - 1) {
    player.setup({ nextUpDisplay: false}) //this reload my player
    }

}
```

How I should do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextUpDisplay` is a static setting. There is no way to change it after setup.

Some player configuration options can be changed after setup using `player.setConfig(options)`. Please file a feature request to make `nextUpDisplay` settable via `player.setConfig` on github https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues and/or customer support.

What you can do in the meantime what you can do is simply hide and show the card using CSS:

```js
const nextUpElement = player.getContainer().querySelector('.jw-nextup-container');
if (nextUpElement) {
  if (player.getPlaylistIndex() === player.getPlaylist().length - 1) {
    nextUpElement.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    nextUpElement.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```